# SQL query for selecting events that occurs at a certain date and time

Tags: php, sql, date

I figure my head around for the best possible query to get the actual event with ! query

This is what I have :

```
$date = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$time = date( 'Gi' );
```

> datasource : http://screencast.com/t/ODthUUpfR

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE startdate = '" . $date . "' AND stopdate >= '" . $date . "' ORDER BY stopdate ASC";
```

The problem I have is if the actual date is 2011-09-15 and the time is 600 (06:00)

The event would be still TeamA 
but with the above query it would return TeamB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should have these stored in two DATETIME fields... you are making it way more complicated by storing this in 4 fields.

Then you should do a query more like

```
WHERE $datetime BETWEEN start_datetime AND end_datetime
```